# How to import an image to IBM Streams?

Tags: image-processing, ibm-streams

Apparently in order to import an image in IBM InfoSphere Streams, (I am currently using the VMware-streams4.1.1) I have to download OpenCV libraries and I have followed this guide. http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.opencv/doc/html/InstallingToolkit.html

And I get to the point where I have to use CMAKE, after that, a make file is created but is not "made" when I type make in the command line...

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH -D OPENCV_EXTRA_C_FLAGS="-DHAVE_CAMV4L -DHAVE_CAMV4L2" -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF ../opencv-3.1.0
make 
sudo make install
```

Is it necessary to download OpenCV to upload images to IBM Streams? or is there any built in libraries already there? Since apparently there is not much information regarding the installation of these libraries.

The main task here is to take the average of an image's pixels in IBM Streams

Answer (score 1):

No, IBM Streams does not have any built-in image processing libraries. However, there is an toolkit for Streams that shows how OpenCV functions can be used in Streams operators. The toolkit contains several dozen examples of operators and applications for processing video streams. The toolkit depends upon OpenCV libraries, which must be installed separately, and they depend upon FFmpeg libraries, which must also be installed.

There are step-by-step instructions for installing FFmpeg and OpenCV libraries, here:

http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.opencv/doc/html/InstallingToolkit.html

After installing the toolkit and libraries, there are suggestions for verifying that everything was installed correctly by executing some of the sample applications, here:

http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.opencv/doc/html/UsingToolkit.html